# Не подключаются стили yii2

Tags: php, css, yii2

Доброго времени суток, кто подскажет, в чем проблема. Не подключаются стили  шаблону. Все файлы в папке web есть. Если подключать через link в шаблоне main.php, то все работает , если подключать через AppAsset, то через дебаг видно, что стили слетают к чертям, а именно папки css вообще не видно.
Консоль выдает такую ошибку для каждого файла:Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

```js
<?php
/**
 * @link http://www.yiiframework.com/
 * @copyright Copyright (c) 2008 Yii Software LLC
 * @license http://www.yiiframework.com/license/
 */

namespace app\assets;

use yii\web\AssetBundle;

/**
 * @author Qiang Xue <qiang.xue@gmail.com>
 * @since 2.0
 */
class AppAsset extends AssetBundle
{
    public $basePath = '@webroot';
    public $baseUrl = '@web';
    public $css = [
        'css/bootstrap.min.css',
        'css/font-awesome.min.css',
        'css/prettyPhoto.css',
        'css/price-range.css',
        'css/animate.css',
        'css/main.css',
        'css/responsive.css',
    ];
    public $js = [
    ];
    public $depends = [
        'yii\web\YiiAsset',
        'yii\bootstrap\BootstrapAsset',
    ];
```

Comment: Отформатируйте код как положено, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не будет работать, так как Вы скорее всего не прописали в самом Layout следующее:

**1)** Нужно зарегистрировать сам **Asset** следующим образом:

```
use app\assets\AppAsset;
AppAsset::register($this);
```

**2)** Нужно указать начало страницы:

```
$this->beginPage();
```

**3)** Для подгрузки стилей и мета тегов нужно указать **Head**:

```
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<!-- Остальной код -->
<? $this->head() ?>
</head>
```

**4)** Указываем начало тега **Body**

```
<? $this->beginBody() ?>
<body>
<!-- Остальной код -->
```

**5)** Указываем завершение тега **Body**:

```
<!-- Остальной код -->
<? $this->endBody() ?>
</body>
```

**6)** В самом конце указываем конец страницы:

```
<? $this->endPage() ?>
```

Это делается для того, чтобы фреймворк Yii знал о том, где подгружать стили и скрипты и все прочее. Стили загружаются в `<head>`, а js-скрипты перед тегом `</body>`. Но опять таки через AsseBundle вы можете отрегулировать положение. Это уже другой вопрос, но все же приведу пример:

```
//Пример. Это нужно указать в AppAsset если хотите, чтобы скрипты подключались в Head
public $jsOptions = ['position' => \yii\web\View::POS_HEAD];
```

Comment: Все это в шаблоне проставлено. Читал документацию, и вообще не первый раз это делаю, но сейчас ничего не получается.

Comment: Не может быть такое. Выложите пожалуйста свой код. Asset сделали, а вот Layout также выложите.

Comment: Cпасибо, разметил все по новой и заработало, возможно до этого все же где-то ошибка была.

Answer (score 1):

а в main.php

```
AppAsset::register($this);
```

есть?

Comment: Есть, но ничего не меняется